# node.js recursive setTimeout() inside of a psuedoclass

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I think I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around the scope of the following code:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter, util = require('util');

// Here is the Ticker constructor:
var Ticker = function(time) {
    this.time = time;
    this.tick = function() {
        this.emit('tick');
        setTimeout(this.tick(), this.time);
    };
}

util.inherits(Ticker, EventEmitter);

var newTicker = new Ticker(1000);

newTicker.on('tick', function() { console.log("TICK"); });

newTicker.tick();
```

What ends up happening, is that the "tick" gets called many, many times filling up the stack without the setTimeout actually setting the timeout to one second.

Could any explain to me what's going on?

---

**EDIT:** I looked a little bit more, and I still couldn't figure out the issue of scope, really.

What I ended up doing was following the solution that was given for the problem, which I tried to solve by way of setTimeout().

The solution given was:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter, util = require('util');

// Here is the Ticker constructor:
var Ticker = function(time) {
    var self = this;
    this.time = time;
    setInterval(function() {
        self.emit('tick');
    }, self.time);
};

util.inherits(Ticker, EventEmitter);

var ticker = new Ticker(1000);

ticker.on('tick', function() { console.log("TICK"); });
```

It does make more sense to me... What I'm wondering now is: Do inner functions and objects in javascript not keep track of their parent's scope and variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial problem is that you were *calling* `this.tick` inside your `setTimeout`:

```javascript
setTimeout(this.tick(), this.time);
```

Instead, you want to pass a *reference* to the `this.tick` function:

```javascript
setTimeout(this.tick, this.time);
```

This fixes the problem for the first loop, but the second call to `tick` (which comes from the `setTimeout`) is not bound to the correct scope; so, you can bind the function reference to the current value of `this` using `bind`:

```javascript
setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), this.time);
```

(You can also use the `self` trick if you prefer.)

So, the full working program is:

```javascript
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter, util = require('util');

// Here is the Ticker constructor:
var Ticker = function(time) {
    this.time = time;
    this.tick = function() {
        this.emit('tick');
        setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), this.time);
    };
}

util.inherits(Ticker, EventEmitter);

var newTicker = new Ticker(1000);

newTicker.on('tick', function() { console.log("TICK"); });

newTicker.tick();
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much.  I came to a similar conclusion after messing with it for some time and ended up using the `self` trick.  Thanks for introducing me to `bind` as well.  Is that more proper rather than relying on a variable?

Comment: I use `bind` (and the CoffeeScript equivalent `=>`) because I think it looks nicer most of the time, but plenty of people use `self`. It's worth noting that some older browsers don't support `Function.prototype.bind`, so `self` may be better in those cases unless you use a shim.